# Como puedo posicionar un div dentro de otro

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

Intento poner un div sobre el contenedor de un div que tiene una imagen, quiero que el cuadro azul se  posicione en la parte punteada de la imagen a la derecha en la letra "T":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="container">
  <div >
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/11/Test-Logo.svg" alt="Workplace" style="position:relative;">

    <div style="border: solid 2px blue; width:10%; height:40%; position:absolute;"></div>
  </div
```

> 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traté de hacer lo más parecido posible a lo que indicas en tu imagen:

```html
<div class="container">
 <div>
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/11/Test-Logo.svg" alt="Workplace" style="position:relative;">
   <div style="border: solid 2px blue; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 90vh; right: 0; width:30vh; height:55%;"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Puedes modificarlo a tu parecer en éste [proyecto](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/zYWoEKd) que tengo preparado.